# How ethereum storageRoot key derived from contract state?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum

In contract account, there is a storageRoot, the Merkle Patricia tree stores all  data about contract state. I want to know how the key and value is derived from state in solidity. In solidity implementation, there are rules about how variable corresponding locations. what's the relation between key and locations? Is there reference I can find the answer? thxs!

Comment: Have you checked the Yellow Paper?

Comment: yeah, I have read the yellow paper. the key problem is how key is derived? in account trie, it is simple, the key is account address. but when it comes to storage trie, i don't know what's the key?